# Specify configs in the ini-formatted file:

Tags: android, node.js, npm, react-native

Noob here,
Im trying to run android emulator installed for my reactnative app to test on vscode online on azure linux machine and getting the follow error:

```
Specify configs in the ini-formatted file:
    /home/vsonline/.npmrc
or on the command line via: npm <command> --key value
Config info can be viewed via: npm help config
```

when I run `npm start-android-emulator` I get the error.
Please any help. I am trying to run react-native code without installing android studio

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should use npx or yarn like this **npx start-android-emulator** or **yarn start-android-emulator**